# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 'cassandraCluster' in spring data cassandra project

Tags: spring, spring-data-cassandra

I'm developing a spring data cassandra based web application for learning purpose and got stuck with following two exceptions.

Exception 1

```
12:18:07.742 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Native - Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.loadNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:87) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:70) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:49) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.findSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:59) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:158) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:89) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:44) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:325) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:304) ~[jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native$LibCLoader.<clinit>(Native.java:108) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Native.isGettimeofdayAvailable(Native.java:190) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory.newInstance(Clock.java:51) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AbstractMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(LoggingMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:49) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:50) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:37) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies.defaultTimestampGenerator(Policies.java:122) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.policies.Policies$Builder.build(Policies.java:287) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.getConfiguration(Cluster.java:1262) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:117) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:182) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1280) [cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraClusterFactoryBean.java:220) [spring-data-cassandra-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Exception 2

```
Error creating bean with name 'cassandraMapping': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#64ed847f' of type [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.SimpleUserTypeResolver] while setting bean property 'userTypeResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#64ed847f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraCluster' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraCluster' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

**I tried adding,**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnr-x86asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnr-ffi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

dependencies as [said in here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/faq/osgi/). But did not work.

My current configurations are as follows.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Javax servlet dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Logging dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Lucene dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

(Spring version 5.0.2 and spring data version 2.0.2)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="advertise"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:system.properties,classpath:cassandra.properties"
                              ignore-resource-not-found="true"
                              ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

<!--Common beans-->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/**" location="file:\${upload.dir}"/>

<cassandra:session keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" schema-action="NONE" />-->

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Cluster -->
<cassandra:cluster id="cluster" contact-points="localhost" port="9042" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Session, built from the Cluster, and attaching
to a keyspace -->
<cassandra:session id="session" keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" cluster-ref="cluster" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Default Cassandra Mapping Context used by CassandraConverter -->
<cassandra:mapping>
    <cassandra:user-type-resolver keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" />
</cassandra:mapping>
<cassandra:converter />
<cassandra:template id="cassandraTemplate" session-ref="session" />
<cassandra:repositories base-package="advertise.orm.d ao" cassandra-template-ref="cassandraTemplate" />
```

I tried to figure, but I'm not sure whether the second bean not found exception is caused by first exception or by a configuration mismatch.
(I'm using spring-mvc with tomcat 8 instead of spring boot.)

If you could help me to solve this problem I'm really thankful.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableCassandraRepositories` annotation in your app? Also, I see `base-package="advertise.orm.d ao"` - is the space character there just from copy/paste here, or it's in your config file as well?

Comment: You can ignore first exception `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown` - it's coming from the optional dependency...

Comment: Sorry, @AlexOtt the space is a mistake while copying and original code doesn't have it. And I don't have `@EnableCassandraRepositories` annotation since I'm trying to config it only through pure xml. I was referring to this part of [spring data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring). It is possible to use xml only configuration right?

By the way thank you for responding.

Comment: Yes, I believe that it should be possible to do only with XML configuration. Unfortunately I don't know Spring bindings very well - it's not officially supported by DataStax.  I think that you need to check that every component correctly referenced by next component, for example, that IDs are correct, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the cluster bean name for `cassandra:user-type-resolver` since you're customizing the cluster bean name in `cassandra:cluster id="cluster"`.

The default bean name is `cassandraCluster`. Changing your XML to:

```
<cassandra:mapping>
    <cassandra:user-type-resolver keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" cluster-ref="cluster"/>
</cassandra:mapping>
```

sets the correct bean name for the user type resolver.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a stupid mistake. I should have thought about this.